# How should a play where the batter-runner misses first base on a double be scored?

Tags: rules, baseball, scoring

The batter hits a fly ball double to center, but the runner does not touch first. The defense appeals and the batter is out 8-4-1-3.

How is the play scored? As a single with an out advancing, or just an out?

Answer (score 2):

[9.05 (a)](https://img.mlbstatic.com/mlb-images/image/upload/mlb/atcjzj9j7wrgvsm8wnjq.pdf) gives the conditions for crediting a hit.  Most of them require that the runner has to make it to first base safely.

This runner did not reach first base safely and is not entitled to a hit.

But to be more explicit, 9.05 (b)(2) states:

> 9.05 (b) The Official Scorer shall not credit a base hit when a:
>
> ...
>
> (2) batter apparently hits safely and a runner who is forced to
> advance by reason of the batter becoming a runner fails to
> touch the first base to which such runner is advancing and
> is called out on appeal. The Official Scorer shall charge
> the batter with a time at bat but no hit;

The runner fails to touch the base required (first) and is out on appeal.  No hit.

Comment: This ignores the more interesting part of the question, though: how is the out scored? A putout by 3? An 8-4-1-3 ground out? A separate category for appeals I've never seen used in a scorecard? :)

Comment: I thought only the batter scoring was in question and the 8-4-1-3 was given.  It is possible (assuming it takes place during the play and not a separate appeal).  If it's a throwover after time was called, score it 1-3 with only the pitcher having an assist.  First base gets a putout in both cases.